# Prevent cronjob's from writing to /var/mail/$USER?

Tags: osx, cron, io-redirection, email, ping

In macOS, cronjobs configured with `crontab` have the command output and/or error messages (if the cron doesn't succeed) written to the `/var/mail/$USER` file. Can this be prevented? I've tried:

```
* * * * *      /sbin/ping -c1 website.com ... 2>&1 >/dev/null
```

Whether it succeeds or fails to reach the domain, the `ping` output is saved to the mail file...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The cron daemon does not write to `/var/mail/$USER`, it sends an email to the user whenever a job outputs anything or fails, which in turn is written to that file (the user's mail inbox) by the system's mail delivery service.

To turn off the sending of email from the cron daemon, set the `MAILTO` variable to an empty value in the crontab file:

```
MAILTO=""

# rest of file with job schedules goes here
```

From the `crontab(5)` manual on a macOS system:

> In addition to `LOGNAME`, `HOME`, and `SHELL`, `cron(8)` will look at `MAILTO` if it has
>        any reason to send mail as a result of running commands in "this" crontab.  If
>        `MAILTO` is defined (and non-empty), mail is sent to the user so named.  If `MAILTO`
>        is defined but empty (`MAILTO=""`), no mail will be sent.  [...]

If you turn off mailing of job output and error notifications in this way, you may want to log the job in some other way, for example,

```
* * * * *      /sbin/ping -c1 website.com ... >>/tmp/ping.log 2>&1
0 0,12 * * *   mv /tmp/ping.log /tmp/ping.log.old
```

This would add the output of `ping` to a specific file, and also move that file away at midnight and noon (note that your redirections to `/dev/null` was back-to-front).

You may also want to explicitly send an email if the `ping` fails:

```
* * * * *      /sbin/ping -c1 website.com ... >>/tmp/ping.log 2>&1 || mail -s "ping failed, do something" "$LOGUSER"
```

This would send an empty email with the specified title whenever `ping` returned a non-zero exit status.

Or, you could just get your redirections right from the start and don't bother with `MAILTO` or logfiles or sending emails:

```
* * * * *      /sbin/ping -c1 website.com ... >/dev/null 2>&1
```

This would send you an email whenever the `ping` failed, but would not send you the output of the command every minute.